# npm install error : using this command "npm install -g @angular/cli"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I try npm install new packages it shows me this error:

rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session dcdf458f5e794f1

nodejs- version:

v8.9.1

npm -version:

5.5.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woP2f.png)

Comment: you have a typo in the linked image

Comment: Means...you are unable to see the image?

Comment: You wrote @amgular/cli in the image. And the error log is related to proxy, so most likely you are behind one and haven't configured npm accordingly

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistake...but again i tried with "npm install -g @angular/cli" command...still the same error log happened

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd as Administrator and write:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I tried this way also...but the same error is coming

Comment: `npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`

Comment: still the same error is coming in command prompt as "rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session dcdf458f5e794f1"

Comment: @sankeerthR :
`npm config rm proxy`
`npm config rm https-proxy`
and restart.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to Update angular/cli (see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
# if npm version is > 5 then use `npm cache verify` to avoid errors (or to avoid using --force)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: i tried this way also...but the same error is coming related to network connectivity